# Bypassing "img-src" csp policy

Tags: javascript, content-security-policy

I'm trying to display an image on a third party website that uses csp policy of "img-src" to disallow every image.
i tried using "background-image" css on an img tag and even on a div tag but no luck.
is this possible at all? or should i ask the site owner to loss the restriction?

Comment: Are you doing it inside an iframe?

Comment: @SujilMaharjan  No I’m not

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no, it is not possible to bypass a site owner's CSP. The whole point of enforcing a CSP on a website is so that the site owner can **block** outside interference for website's security.

Doing a [quick search for "bypassing a csp"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bypassing+a+csp) returned some results, but these samples are typically in very specific scenarios. So technically, yes, it can be possible to bypass a CSP through penetration testing and limited situations, but I wouldn't rely on these because they may be fixed in the future, and your workaround based on the vulnerability may be closed.

Your best bet is to contact the site owner and ask that they whitelist your site in their `img-src` directive so that it will show up correctly.